Why is Angular saying my ngFor variable should be binded in the component?
I have the following ngFor statement where I am iterating over colorImgs with 'color' as the variable:
 <div class="me-2">
   <ng-content ngFor="let color of colorImgs">
       <img class="highlight-border-2" src="assets/img/{{color.img}}">
   </ng-content>
 </div>

I am getting the following error message about color.img:

Property 'color' does not exist on type 'SelectedProductComponent'.ngtsc(2339)
selected-product.component.ts(14, 57): Error occurs in the template of component SelectedProductComponent.


You're missing the * on *ngFor="" which is what adds "color" to the current context.
Also you may not want to use ng-content with a for loop.
You can't usually have more than one of those, unless they have some selector (look up Content Projection Angular).
